# IOS application Application Files Migration

Tags: ios, migration

I am working on a application that is a sort of video recorder, but i'm facing a problem, while coredata could support keeping data on migration (install uppdate, reinstall program), applications files save to the document folder of the app are deleted. I'm using a webservice for some images, but all the video recorded by the user are lost.

Is there a way to keep application local files (in the document folder) while migrating (like relaunching the app from xcode without deleting it on the phone) ?

I'm talking about path like :

```
filePath    NSString *  @"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7FB440BB-76DD-49C6-B5DD-AA9D26A86C51/Documents/dataImage/image_1_maquette_miniature.jpg"  0x000000015c528520
```

EDIT :
I've found that, when i rebuild my app:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/509E8B5D-A3C4-4D90-809B-47159AC60542/Documents/dataImage/image_1_gabarit_masque.png

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/660EF541-CDD0-439C-BCAB-B7FE4371799A/Documents/dataImage/image_1_gabarit_masque.png
```

The UUID changes so here is my code to write files:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

if(![self createFolderIfNoExists:@"dataImage"]) {
    fileManager = nil;
    return nil;
}

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dataImage/image_%d_%@.%@",objectID,assetTypeName,extension]];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath] == YES) {
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
    NSLog(@"DELETE file exists %d",[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);
}
if([imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO] == NO) {
    NSLog(@"[Error] Create File %@ at %@", imageData,filePath);
    fileManager = nil;
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: It is not true that files in the document directory get delete on update. Yes they do get the deleted when you remove the app, but that als true for the CoreData. Since the CoreData data base is also saved in the document directory.

Comment: Ok, maybe i'm missing something, when i relaunch (recompile and launch) images are disappearing, so i guess this is not the same behavior as upgrading the app. But still i don't understand why images are missing.
It must be something in my code.

Comment: I mean on rebuild and launch on the Iphone, coredata data is still here, but local files are reset

Comment: Well I've never seen that happen, I recompile en relaunch my apps on multiple test device very often. And never ever have I lost files from the documents directory.

Comment: I've edited my post, seems like the UUID changes on rebuild, are you using the same king of code or something elese ?

Comment: Just don't save the full path, but only the relative path from the document directory.